# JavaScript Function Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

How would I use a function that returns the sum of a given array while getting the sum of the even numbers and sum the odd numbers? I'm not understanding how that is done. Can someone please explain a little more in depth?

Here is my entire code:

```
    function main()
{
    var evenNum = 0;
    //need a total Even count
    var oddNum = 0;
    //need a total Odd count
    var counter = 1;
    var num = 0;

function isOdd(x) {

    if ((num % 2) == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function isEven(x) {

    if ((num % 2) == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

for (counter = 1; counter <= 100; counter++)
{
    num = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * (100-1));

    var total = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < length; j++)
    total += a[j];//Array?

    console.log(num);

console.log("The count of even number is " + evenNum);
console.log("The count of odd number is " + oddNum);

return 0;
}

main()
```

Comment: I dont understand your question, and you have not done a good job explaining what you have tried, or what is causing you trouble.

Comment: Please show us your code. If it isn't working for some reason or another, that is what we're here to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need a function that returns two values, one for the sum of even numbers and one for the sum of odd numbers. It's not clear if you use even/odd referring to the index of the array or the values in array.

In both cases you can return an object that contains both values:

```
function sum(array) {
   var evenSum = 0;
   var oddSum = 0;

   ...calculate...

   var res = {};
   res.evenSum = evenSum;
   res.oddSum = oddSum;

   return res;
}
```

Hope this will help